# How to refer to a chapter with a word

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I would like to refer to my chapters with the notation "First Chapter", "Second Chapter" etc, rather than "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2", etc. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
%Loaded here: microtype,graphicx,booktabs,caption,tabularx,hyperref,amsmath
\usepackage{classicthesis-preamble}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

% A personalization of description environment
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}\small\textsc{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{MyChapter}
\label{ch:first}

\begin{description}
\item [In the \ref{ch:first}] I yada yada yada
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The right package to use, along with `refcount`, is `numname`:

```
\usepackage{refcount,numname}
\newcommand{\refc}[1]{\ordinaltoName{\getrefnumber{#1}} Chapter}

In the \refc{ch:first} we do something.
```

To get also a link,

```
\newcommand{\refc}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\ordinaltoName{\getrefnumber{#1}} Chapter}}
```

Comment: Also here, the text is ok but it doesn't link to the chapter.

Comment: @Baduel See edited message

Comment: Thanks. How can I have the same result with the Appendix?

Comment: I've found the answer: `\autoref` =)

Answer (score 8):

You may use something like

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
%Loaded here: microtype,graphicx,booktabs,caption,tabularx,hyperref,amsmath
\usepackage{classicthesis-preamble}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

% A personalization of description environment
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}\small\textsc{#1}}

\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand*{\refc}[1]{%
  \setrefcountdefault{0}%

  \hyperref[#1]{\ifcase\getrefnumber{#1}
  ???
  \or First
  \or Second
  \or Third
  % please extend this on your own
  \else A kind of yellow
  \fi Chapter}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{MyChapter}
\label{ch:first}

\begin{description}
\item [In the \refc{ch:first}] I yada yada yada
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

to do this. There's also a package [engord](http://ctan.org/pkg/engord) for english ordinals, that may be used instead of a `\ifcase` construct.

**Alternative** you may patch `\refstepcounter` and redefine `\p@chapter` to make all `\ref` to a chapter to be text references:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
%Loaded here: microtype,graphicx,booktabs,caption,tabularx,hyperref,amsmath
\usepackage{classicthesis-preamble}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

% A personalization of description environment
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}\small\textsc{#1}}

\makeatletter
% 1. Allow \p@… to be a command with an argument
\renewcommand*\refstepcounter[1]{\stepcounter{#1}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel
  {\csname p@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
% Then ignore this argument at `\p@chapter` and use the completely different
% output instead.
\renewcommand\p@chapter[1]{\ordinalnumbertext{\value{chapter}} \@chapapp}%
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\ordinalnumbertext}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1
  ???
  \or First
  \or Second
  \or Third
  \else A kind of yellow
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{MyChapter}
\label{ch:first}

\begin{description}
\item [In the \ref{ch:firsta}] I yada yada yada
\end{description}

\appendix
\chapter{MyChapter}
\label{ch:firsta}

\begin{description}
\item [In the \ref{ch:first}] I yada yada yada
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

This does even work with appendices like shown in the example.

Comment: The text is right, but `refc` doesn't refer!

Comment: @Baduel: It did refer but it didn't link to. I've changed the first example, to solve this. The second links too.